# flot.js: Customizing legend

Tags: jquery, flot, pie-chart

How can I customize the legend on flot.pie.js?

I have the following code:

```
var options = { 
            series: { 
                pie: {
                    show: true
                },
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    label: {
                        show: true,
                        formatter: function(label, series){
                            return '<div style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;">' + label + ' ' + Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

That's not working though, I think I'm making up the legend part... What I want is to show the values on the legend. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry to respond on this around 4 years late,.. but the problem in the above question was that `formatter` in the above code should have been `labelFormatter`. Although the accepted answer is right(in a way since it manipulates data for formatting), the other answer that is not accepted and was given 2 years later seems like the optimal solution.... Can you just please mention this in the question(for people like me who stumble on this question)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the data value to your series label.  You didn't show your data, so imagine that your data looks like this:

```
var data = [
    {
    label: "Good",
    data: 10},
{
    label: "Bad",
    data: 30 },
{
    label: "Ugly",
    data: 90},
];
```

Then you could use this code to append the data value to each label:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data[i].label+=' ('+data[i].data+')'
}
```

Here is how it would look:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/p8fzS/

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
function legendFormatter(label, series) {
    return '<div ' + 
           'style="font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:2px;">' +
           label + ' ' + Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>';
};

var options = { 
    series: { 
        pie: {
            show: true
        },
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        labelFormatter: legendFormatter
    }
};
```

working Example Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Rnusy/322/

Comment: Thanks.Works Great for me too.